# How to repeat jumping n lines down in vim

Tags: vim

I can jump n lines down by typing
`4j`
for example.

How to repeat this conveniently? I found that `.` does not do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe that there is any built in feature to repeat arbitrary motions.

If you don't mind plugins [repmo](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=2174) seems to do what you want. It defaults repeating motion forward to `;` and repeating motion backwards to `,`.

Answer (score 0):

Macro might suit well for this http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/01/vi-and-vim-macro-tutorial-how-to-record-and-play/

Comment: how could this possibly help?

Comment: You record macro which does for example 4j and than play it with @a

Comment: oh i see. but it is not very `convenient`. :)

Comment: I agree. If you were moving through a massive file 4 lines at a time, you could repeatedly press `@` to do it.